# How to parse a json list?

Tags: python, json

I've a json list:

```
tcp_packet = {'green': [], 'red': [{'arm_id': 2, 'pptl_id': [1]}, {'arm_id': 1, 'pptl_id': [1]}]}
```

I need to check whether arm_id exists in 'red' or not?

currently i have to loop around `tcp_packet['red']` to find out whether `arm_id = 2` exists or not?

```
for i in tcp_packet[color]:
   if '2' in i.keys():
       do something
```

is there a one-line solution to this?

Comment: is `one-liner` a requirement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
do_something() if 2 in [x.get('arm_id') for x in tcp_packet['red']] else None
```

Comment: I know list comprehension. But can't it be done without using a loop?

Comment: you have to loop through the values of tcp_packet['red'] because it is a list

Comment: I have fixed 2 to be an integer rather than string in the if statement.

Comment: Also use x.get('arm_id') so that you don't get a KeyError if arm_id is not in the dict.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit unclear from your question, but is this what you are looking for?

```
>>> tcp_packet = {'green': [], 'red': [{'arm_id': 2, 'pptl_id': [1]}, {'arm_id': 1, 'pptl_id': [1]}]}
>>> any((('arm_id', 2) in i.iteritems()) for i in tcp_packet['green'])
False
>>> any((('arm_id', 2) in i.iteritems()) for i in tcp_packet['red'])
True
```